# Can not connect my iPhone via USB to XCode if it was previously connected wirelessly

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, wireless

I have iPhone 15 Pro Max that I am using in Development of iOS application. Previously, I was debugging/launching the app in XCode through wireless connection. So far, so good - but today I have encountered a problem that I can not fetch application content to my Mac for further inspection. Each time I download a package, it gives me different sizes and content is not presented in full. So I think there must be something wrong with wireless connection and decided to give a go using USB connection.

But when I connected my iPhone via USB, XCode does not see it at all. I relaunched XCode couple of times, no luck and I am not sure what exactly is going wrong here.

So my question is in the title - how to connect iPhone via USB connection to XCode if it was previously connected wirelessly?

Answer (score 1):

I had encountered this problem,

Just restart your iPhone, I think that may be some caches inside phone.

Comment: Yeah, it does seem like some "glitch", not a well-known bug or expected behaviour. Instead I have rebooted Mac completely, not only XCode, seemed to help

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess I have found an answer (sort of)

I rebooted my Mac and hit "Clear Trusted Computers" on iPhone prior to that.

Once mac is booted, my phone was not in it's radar for wireless connection. And I connected to it via USB and now I have USB connection. Sorry for choppy explanation, writing this answer in a rush